# Draw boxes with text inside

Tags: boxes, text, draw

Can anybody show me how to do the boxes in the image attached in latex.

Thanks ahead

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? You can use simple frame boxes with struts or fancier TikZ boxes. See e.g. [How to create command for a box where text inside the box can automatically adjust?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/84074)

Comment: Also [How can I insert a newline in a framebox?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/8680)

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mybox/.style={minimum width=4cm,draw,thick,align=center,minimum height=1.8cm}]
\node[mybox,label=above:$\alpha$] (alpha) {1,2,3};
\node[right=1cm of alpha,mybox,label=above:$\beta$] (beta)  {4,5,6};
\node[right=1cm of beta,mybox,label=above:$\gamma$] (gamma)  {7,8,9};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]