# use pdfpages package to include a form and manipulate the page

Tags: diagrams, pdfpages

I am using the **pdfpages** package to include 3 pages of another PDF. The other PDF is interchangeable, i.e. there are multiple Versions of it which are all similar though. It is actaully a form (not a PDF form though!).

I'd like to somehow include this kind of PDF and be able to manipulate the content of one of the pages.

The Form has fields (for humans) to fill firstname and last name and some address information.

It would be nice to just exchange the PDF, but not have to fill out this meta data every time.

Is it possible to draw something over the pages that were included by using pdfpages `\includepdf` command?

I found this question here [Draw boxes with text inside](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437979/draw-boxes-with-text-inside) and the answer uses the TikZ package.

But how would I tell LaTeX to draw these boxes on the included pages?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You can do this in a few ways. I like my `pdfoverlay` package which I wrote for this purpose. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473833/87678

Comment: Possibly this question is a duplicate of the one I linked to (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15314/87678). Does one of the answers there suit you?

Comment: @DavidPurton thanks for your comments, i will have a look into the docs and probably come back with questions ;)